# arraylist loading gives me interesting output

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

i have this simple method:

```
    public static Map<String, ArrayList<String>> szamolando = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> outputs = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0;i<2;i++){
tombFeltolt("a"+i);
}
public void tombFeltolt(String kimenet) {
        outputs.clear();
        System.out.println("1");
        outputs.add(min);
        System.out.println("2");
        outputs.add(max);
        System.out.println("3");
        outputs.add("65535");

        szamolando.put(kimenet, outputs);
    }
```

than i've got this output: 1 2 3 2

why do i got this?What is wrong with my method?Thank You for your answers!

Edit:
okay here is the complete code:

```
 public static Map<String, ArrayList<String>> szamolando = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    static ArrayList<String> outputs = new ArrayList<String>();
    static String min, max;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                min = "10";
                max = "20";
            } else {

                min = "9";
                max = "8";
            }
            tombFeltolt("a" + i);
        }
        for (String name : szamolando.keySet()) {

            String key = name.toString();
            String value = szamolando.get(name).toString();
            System.out.println("ASS " + key + " " + value);

        }
    }

    public static void tombFeltolt(String kimenet) {
        outputs.clear();
        System.out.println("1");
        outputs.add(min);
        System.out.println("2");
        outputs.add(max);
        System.out.println("3");
        outputs.add("65535");

        szamolando.put(kimenet, outputs);
    }
```

and here is my output:

> ASS a0 [9, 8, 65535]
>   ASS a1 [9, 8, 65535]

Comment: What is min and max ?

Comment: What output were you expecting?  Are you referring to your `println` calls, or something else?

Comment: What do you want the output to be? Right now (to state the obvious) you are just printing what you hardcoded strings in your println statements

Comment: min,max are simple strings.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you have used to print the values.

Comment: try debugging it otherwise pls post the complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change this:

```
static ArrayList<String> outputs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to this:

```
static ArrayList<String> outputs = null;
```

and put this line into your 'for' loop:

```
outputs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: yes,  it seems that this was the error now i get the right output!Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the source of your problem
When you do a clear, it will clear the ArrayList which still references to the existing ArrayList which will clear the stored list as well coz it has stored the reference.
if you want 10, 20, 65535 use new list everytime.

```
 outputs.clear();
```